# Validation for few not saved objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have form, that creates some objects in batch. For my flow i have to either save them all at once, or not save at all. Problem is - when I do my validations, they are not failing, since each object, validates according to current records in db(i have uniqueness validation), but i also need to validate current object to each of my unsaved objects. Small example

```
class User
    #field: email
end
```

In my form object i have an array of users. And in loop i do

```
@users.each do |user|
  valid_users << user if user.valid?   #and this is where i need to validate `user` within not just DB, but within @users aswell
end
```

How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to check if all the unsaved object pass the validation test or not, if yes, to do that you can do this instead for the unique field `email`

```
if @users.map { |user| user.email.downcase }.uniq.length == @users.size
  @users.each do |user|
    valid_users << user if user.valid?   
  end
else
  # Error: Emails of the users must be unique
end
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap them in a transaction which will roll back the entire batch if one fails.

```
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    @users.map(&:save!)
  end
rescue  ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just check the `user.valid`? that validates the DB records and then manually check the `@users` and only save if it's not a duplicate.

```
@users.each do |user|

  #the following would check for identical objects in @users, but that may not be what you want
  valid_users << user if user.valid? and @users.count(user)<2

  #this would check only the required field on the array
  valid_users << user if user.valid? and @users.map(&:email).count(user.email)<2

end
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this, can be using [`all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F):

```
if @users.all?{|u| u.valid? } # true, only when all users are validated
   # save all users
else
   # redirect/render with error message.
end
```

Comment: this wont check if there are any collisions in scope on not-saved collection, e.g. 2 users with same email

Comment: @Avdept : Well, that wasn't mentioned anywhere in the question.